# How can i get request url from flask app?

Tags: python, flask, request

I have a flask app on a server. That flask app is launch with that code.

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=True, port=3001,threaded=True)
```

When i try to reach that app with servers public ip. I can get full headers.
I get headers with `dict(request.headers)`.

On my dockerhost i have 30 container that looks the same address with flask app. What i mean is;

public-ip:3001/test and my.sites.example.com/test goes that flask app.
if i call public-ip:3001/test i get my public ip as host. When i call my.sites.example.com/test i get 0.0.0.0:3001/test as host. I am trying to get my.sites.example.com.

My nginx settings are; for docker containers:

```
  location /test/ {
    proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:3001/test/;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  }
```

For the server:

```
 location / {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }
```

My main goal is to get the client's request url. public-ip:3001/test and my.sites.example.com/test goes that flask app. if i call public-ip:3001/test i get my public ip as host. When i call my.sites.example.com/test i get 0.0.0.0:3001/test as host. I am trying to get my.sites.example.com.